# Deciphering Facebook Pixel Code to add `preconnect` or `dns-prefetch`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies, seo, facebook-pixel

I want to add `preconnect` or `dns-prefetch` to the standard Facebook Pixel code in order to prevent delays to my site loading.

The standard code is:

```
<script>
  !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s)
  {if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
  n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};
  if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';
  n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
  t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
  'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
  fbq('init', '{your-pixel-id-goes-here}');
  fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
```

Obviously it's quite difficult to see whats going on and therefore where to add the attribute.

Does anyone know what the full breakdown of the code is therefore where a good place to add is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Both preconnect and dns-prefetch require the domain that is going to be requested. In this case, it is: https://connect.facebook.net

You could also look at all the requests that Facebook makes on a page to see if other domains could be added.

This will only slightly increase the speed of the Facebook tracking code. It is code that runs asynchronously, so it is unlikely that it will make any difference to the user's perceived load time. The rest of the page loads as the Facebook code loads and runs.